# 4 alternative ways to calculate text height in a UITextVIew (iOS7+), but which one is the right way?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I got the following 4 ways to get text height in an UITextView. I found the values could be different. According to my test, sometimes method1 and method4 are correct and sometimes method3 is right. I could not figure out how those could happen.

```
//method 1
    float fudgeFactor = [self getTextViewLeftMargin:textView];
        CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor*2,999);

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
            stringSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        } else {
            stringSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        }

        CGFloat textHeight = stringSize.height;

//method2:     
        CGFloat textHeight2 = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height;

//method3:    
        CGFloat textHeight3 = textView.contentSize.height;

//method4:
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
                NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;
                NSDictionary *attr = @{NSFontAttributeName: textView.font};
                CGRect labelBounds = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:tallerSize
                                                                 options:options
                                                              attributes:attr
                                                                 context:nil];

                CGFloat textHeight = labelBounds.size.height;
```

Comment: I always use method 3 (contentSize)

Comment: @andlin, I found it's better to use sizeThatFits. Above 4 methods are required to be updated after a runloop. That is to say it could be a problem if you do that just after resizing text size or frame